# RDP from Win8 to XP Pro Suddenly Stopped Working - "Can't Connect to Remote Computer"

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp, remote-desktop, terminal-services

A colleague of mine has RDP set up on her win8 home computer to connect to her XP Pro work computer on a different network. She had this running on her Win8 desktop and Win8 laptop and they were both working. A while back they suddenly stopped working (I don't know the exact date but sometime late August/early September). It's giving the usual "RDP Can't connect to the remote computer" message. I thought for sure that her external IP had changed and was no longer allowed through the office router, but it is still the same.

I can connect fine from my home computers (win7 and xp) to her work computer. Her home computer can ping the office network. Her windows firewall is disabled and I tried disabling Avast as well. Her home network is private. I tried messing with the RDP settings, like disabling printer sharing, disabling audio and changing the quality/resolution. I looked through her system/application event logs and did not find anything related to remote desktop connections or terminal services.

Since RDP on both her computers stopped working at the same time, I'm thinking this might be caused by a Win8 update. There are a lot of posts online with people claiming RDP stopped working after a Win8 update, but I looked through tons of them and have still not found a solution that works. I'm also not sure how to troubleshoot and confirm that this is in fact related to a windows update.

So I know the issue is with her home computers/network since I can RDP fine from my home. It's not related to the firewall or RDP settings (I think).

If anyone has any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this and narrow down the problem, that would be great! Right now the only information I have to go on is the generic error message from RDP.

Comment: There may be an update for RDP for XP. Check optional Windows updates on the XP pc. [Or use this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969084)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the IP did change but the internal one, not the external one. There are free remote access apps out there you can use to take control of her computer and then investigate the router from the inside.

When you open up port 3389, you forward it to a specific address, unless the router offers a way to keep track like a reservation, MAC address, etc. so if the IP address changes, the router will automatically adjust.

Since she has a desktop, you could also just assign a static IP address to your computer so it never changes. Just make sure you use something outside the DHCP range so that address doesn't get assigned in the future to another device, which would cause an IP conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have checked the configuration on the destination machines and everything is correct.
You need to narrow down the problem a little further. YOU can connect to the office machines so you know they will respond. But you are using XP and Win 7 to do it and she is using Win8. 
I would start small and then expand from there. Can she connect to another machine on her own network? Setup a laptop on her network then have her connect to it. Use an XP laptop if you have one, but first prove that she can connect to another device -at all.
If that works then something must be obstructing the pathway between her network and the destination machines.
So my next question would be:
Can she connect to any other machine on any other network? How about your XP box at your home? can she connect to that? Is there any other machine on any other network that can be setup for her to connect to?
Prove that she can get out of her own network and connect to something else.
If this fails check her router/modem configuration, it may be blocking the traffic. if it passes then the company router might be blocking it, or the destination machine is not accepting the connection from her.
I hope this leads you to the issue, let me know what you find.
-larryc